# Why does this function return True for this variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

Taking an online course on python and the assignment was to break the loop and make the function work properly. While I was able to solve the problem, I did not understand why the function returns (and is supposed to) "True" for number 8.

Could you please explain?

```
def is_power_of_two(n):
  while n % 2 == 0 and n != 0:
    n = n / 2
  if n == 1:
    return True
  return False

print(is_power_of_two(0)) # False
print(is_power_of_two(1)) # True
print(is_power_of_two(8)) # True
print(is_power_of_two(9)) # False
```

Here is how I interpreted it:

1. 8 divided 2 gives a remainder of 0: First condition is met.
2. 8 is not equal to 0: Second condition is met.
3. If (while) both conditions are met, the number (8) is divided by 2 and this value (4) is assigned to variable n.
4. Finally, it checks if the variable n (4) is equal to 1. Since 4 is not equal 1 it should return False, but instead it returns True. Why is that?

Comment: "If (while) both conditions are met, the number (8) is divided by 2 and this value (4) is assigned to variable n." Okay, and then what? "Finally, it checks if the variable n (4) is equal to 1." Why? It seems as though you expect `if` and `while` to mean the same thing. They do not - either in Python or in English.

Comment: Hint: why do you suppose we call it a "while *loop*"?

Comment: Side-note: Odds are you should be implementing this with `//` (`int`-based floor division), not `/` (`float` based "true division", with decimal point); without floor division, you're ending up with floating point results (which may not work properly for large inputs, and end up doing unnecessary work to finally reach 0).

Comment: Hi @ShadowRanger, would you be able to give an example? From what I see, `float` numbers are eliminated by modulo in this function. So, I would not expect this to affect performance.

Comment: @KonstantinAndreyev: Side-note: [There's a *much* faster way to check for powers of two](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#DetermineIfPowerOf2).

Comment: @KonstantinAndreyev: I agree it won't lose performance (I misread it initially). So it's just the correctness for large inputs issue. For a broken example, consider `(2 ** 54) + 2` as an input; clearly not a power of 2, but thanks to the implicit conversion to an imprecise `float`, the extra `+ 2` gets lost and it says it's a power of 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"If" and "while" don't mean quite the same thing, either in English or in Python (in English the difference is similar to ["when" vs "while"](https://www.englishcurrent.com/grammar/difference-while-when-conjunctions/)).

The `while` loop repeats **while** (as long as) the condition is true; it doesn't only happen once **if** the condition is true.  *As long as* the condition is met, the body of the loop is executed, and then the condition is re-checked.  For the starting value n = 8, the loop is executed three times before it stops.  Each time the body of the loop is executed, `n` is halved.

1. `n = 8`: 8 is even and not 0, so the loop executes and continues.
2. `n = 4`: 4 is even and not 0, so the loop executes and continues.
3. `n = 2`: 2 is even and not 0, so the loop executes and continues.
4. `n = 1`: 1 is not even, so the loop ends.
5. After the loop: n = 1, so we return True.